# Ajuda para debugar no visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debug

Existe alguma maneira no estúdio visual de um ponto de interrupção para outro tipo de coisa que está entre eles?

Eu possuo um sistema gigante e complexo, que quase sempre chega até onde eu quero, e é necessário passar por capturas de tela. Então, para eu fazer um teste em uma página, eu perco muito tempo passando por outras, inserindo dados, conexão com banco ...

Se alguém tiver alguma dica de como eu posso fazer, ou como vocês fazem para debugar.

Utilize o visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você aperta o **F9** (Toggle BreakPoint) com a linha selecionada você coloca um breakpoint, apertando F9 novamente você tira o breakpoint.

Atalhos caso bata no breakpoint:
**F10**: para ir pulando de linha em linha por alto (Step Over)
**F11**: para ir pulando e analisando dentro do código (Step Into)
**F5**: para pular para o próximo breakpoint (Continue)

**CTRL+ALT+B**: abre a janela que mostra os breakpoints, é útil para navegação e para limpar breakpoints que você não está analisando mais

**Você já conhece o workflow do código?**
Se não, você vai ter que entender, passar pelo menos uma vez por todos os passos e colocando breakpoints onde você quiser analisar. Quando eu debugo e tem um **for** por exemplo, eu coloco um breakpoint mais perto do ponto futuro onde eu quero analisar e dou continue (F5) aí você vai pulando de breakpoint a breakpoint e evita ficar rodeando num loop que dependendo do tamanho da lista, levaria um bom tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Extra:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Você também pode filtrar seus breakpoints através de condições, verificando os valores das variáveis de acordo com a sua necessidade.